# a way to avoid using empty array when tracking repetetive data

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, refactoring

I have a function that creates a table with cities and weather conditions in those cities. It checks cityArr and if the city that came from request is not there, it creates a new table row and adds data to it. Otherwise it finds the row with the city and replaces it with fresh data.

I am looking for a way to keep the same functionality but somehow avoid using an array and check for existing cities some other way.

```js
const cityArr = []; // don't like using array

export function makeTable() {
    const storageCity = localStorage.getItem('city');

    if (cityArr.includes(storageCity)) {
        tbody.deleteRow(cityArr.indexOf(storageCity));
        makeRowsandCells(cityArr.indexOf(storageCity), " UPDATE");

    } else {
        makeRowsandCells();
        cityArr.push(storageCity);
    }

    if (tbody.children[0]) {
        table.classList.add('table-visible');
    }    
};

function makeRowsandCells(index = -1, update = '') {
    const row = tbody.insertRow(index);
    const cityCell = row.insertCell();
    cityCell.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('city') + update;
    const cityCell1 = row.insertCell();
    cityCell1.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('country');
    const cityCell2 = row.insertCell();
    cityCell2.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('temp');
    const cityCell3 = row.insertCell();
    cityCell3.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('feelslike');
};
```

Comment: If you don't like array, you could use an object ?

Comment: I tried creating and stringifying an object and save it in localStorage keeping all of the city names there but retrieving data from there seems bothersome because you have to parse it and cycle through keys to look for a city